# Pandas not plotting code.

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, quantitative-finance

I'm new to coding and am trying to understand a lecture on Quantopian by going through the code but when I run the code in PyCharm, there is no output. Can someone tell me what's going on and advise me on how to resolve this?

Below is my a piece of code (2.7.13):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
# just set the seed for the random number generator
np.random.seed(107)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_returns = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100) # Generate the daily returns
# sum them and shift all the prices up into a reasonable range
X = pd.Series(np.cumsum(X_returns), name='X') + 50
X.plot();
```

The sole output, when I run this, is: "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: It seems you need `plt.show()` in the end.

Comment: @jezrael: thanks a lot. that seems to solve the problem. Was unaware of this :)

Comment: Probably don't need a `;` at the end though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add plt.show() at the end:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
# just set the seed for the random number generator
np.random.seed(107)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_returns = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100) # Generate the daily returns
# sum them and shift all the prices up into a reasonable range
X = pd.Series(np.cumsum(X_returns), name='X') + 50
X.plot()
plt.show()
```